# Get image created date before upload in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_filter' );
 function custom_upload_filter( $file ){
             $dd1 = date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($file['file'])); 
              $file['name'] = $dd1 . $file['name'];
             return $file;
        }
```

I want created date before image upload using media in wordpress but it gives me 1 January 1970 how can i get created date of image

Comment: PHP doesn't upload this information so it is not available. You will need to use JavaScript FILE API to get the data and append this information to your upload form (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

Comment: Ok Thank you i'll check it

Comment: How can i get upload image file path from remote desktop any idea @jeff

Comment: Unclear what you are asking with that last comment. You don’t get the actual client-side path on the server - that is none of your business. And what “remote desktop” has to do with any of this - also unclear.

Comment: @ekta you can't and it is not relevant as you will be storing the file on the web server.

Comment: Ok thank you so much